# Getting EOFException with embeded tomcat 7

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, tomcat7, java-7

I am trying to run simple web application using maven and embaded tomacat.

```
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/main/STShapeType.class] from Jar [jar:jndi:/localhost/WEB-INF/lib/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-beta4.jar!/] for annotations
java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.FastDataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(FastDataInputStream.java:120)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readAttributes(ClassParser.java:110)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:94)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2071)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1947)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1913)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1898)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1330)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5380)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Jun 09, 2015 3:18:00 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [ucar/nc2/dt/fmrc/ForecastModelRunInventory$VertCoord.class] from Jar [jar:jndi:/localhost/WEB-INF/lib/netcdf-4.2-min.jar!/] for annotations
java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.FastDataInputStream.readInt(FastDataInputStream.java:145)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readID(ClassParser.java:200)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2071)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1947)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1913)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1898)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1330)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5380)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Jun 09, 2015 3:18:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [ucar/unidata/geoloc/ProjectionImpl.class] from Jar [jar:jndi:/localhost/WEB-INF/lib/netcdf-4.2-min.jar!/] for annotations
java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.FastDataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(FastDataInputStream.java:120)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Utility.swallowFieldOrMethod(Utility.java:75)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readMethods(ClassParser.java:235)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2071)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1947)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1913)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1898)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1330)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5380)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Jun 09, 2015 3:18:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/objects/Object2IntAVLTreeMap$KeyIterator.class] from Jar [jar:jndi:/localhost/WEB-INF/lib/fastutil-5.0.9.jar!/] for annotations
java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.FastDataInputStream.readInt(FastDataInputStream.java:145)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readID(ClassParser.java:200)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2071)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1947)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1913)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1898)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1330)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5380)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Jun 09, 2015 3:18:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [it/unimi/dsi/fastutil/objects/Reference2ByteOpenHashMap.class] from Jar [jar:jndi:/localhost/WEB-INF/lib/fastutil-5.0.9.jar!/] for annotations
java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.FastDataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(FastDataInputStream.java:120)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.Utility.swallowFieldOrMethod(Utility.java:75)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readMethods(ClassParser.java:235)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2071)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1947)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1913)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1898)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1330)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5380)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Jun 09, 2015 3:18:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig processAnnotationsJar
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [org/bouncycastle/jce/provider/BrokenJCEBlockCipher$BrokePBEWithMD5AndDES.class] from Jar [jar:jndi:/localhost/WEB-INF/lib/bcprov-jdk15-1.45.jar!/] for annotations
java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.FastDataInputStream.readInt(FastDataInputStream.java:145)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.readID(ClassParser.java:200)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassParser.parse(ClassParser.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsStream(ContextConfig.java:2071)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar(ContextConfig.java:1947)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsUrl(ContextConfig.java:1913)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotations(ContextConfig.java:1898)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1330)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5380)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Jun 09, 2015 3:18:04 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

Comment: I suggest the file `ucar/nc2/dt/fmrc/ForecastModelRunInventory$VertCoord.class` is corrupt. Have you checked?

Comment: I am using maven and it loads all the jar from repository. so I don't think that there is issue with jar.

Answer (score 1):

What is your tomcat versiono?
This is bug in tomcat and it was resolved. 
See here: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57173